# How do you get cron job running Node.js script to read variables from .env file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, cron, environment-variables

I've currently got a cron job setup where it runs a Node.js script. The Node.js script uses the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to read a `.env` file that has some API keys.

When I run the Node.js script from the command line, the variables are read correctly from the `.env` file and works with my Node.js script.

But when cron runs the Node.js script, the variables that I'm trying to set return undefined.

```
00 05 * * * /home/michaellee/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.0/bin/node /home/michaellee/index.js >> /home/michaellee/output.log
```

The `.env` file resides in the same level as the `index.js` file.

The cron job is set using `crontab -e` from the user `michaellee`, the same user that has the files on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

I just change the path on dotenv config and it worked for me

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');    
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '/../.env' });
```

Comment: Very nice! I'm glad to help you! :)

Comment: Just ran into this issue, and applied this fix to great success.  Thanks!  Can anyone explain why this is necessary?  What is cron doing differently when it runs my script compared to when I run manually?

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be less of a headache to take the contents out of the `.env` file and load them into a JSON file. Then, you can just `require` the JSON file and load in the data. Much each & doesn't require any plugins, & it would work w/ Cron seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks @Colby for your suggestion! I gave it a shot it worked really well. I was concerned of putting API keys in a JSON file. Then I realized, I just needed to ignore it so it never gets versioned.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad it worked well for you! I've found that anything Node usually works best w/ JSON format. Good luck!